# Erro ao tentar mover arquivo para uma pasta com PHP e JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando mover arquivos de uma pasta. Esse arquivos são listados, a partir do momento que são criado, quero movê-los ao final do dia para uma determinada pasta de back-up. Porém, ao chamar a function PHP responsável por isso, nada faz.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="50000">
        <title></title>
        <head>
                 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function moveFile(fileName) {
              $.ajax({
                url:'copyFile.php',
                type: "GET",
                complete: function (fileName) {
                 alert("Arquivo foi movido!");
               },
               error: function () {
                alert('Erro');
              }
            });  
              return false;
            }
          </script>
        </head>
      </head>
      <body>
          <?php



      if(isset($_GET['path']))
        $dir =  $_GET['path'];
      else
        $dir = 'fileInfo/';
      foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $file) {
        if (!$file->isDot()) {
          if ($file->isDir()) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<a href="index.php?path='.$dir. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$file.'"></a><br/>' . $file->getBaseName();
            echo '</div>';
          } else {
            switch($file->getExtension()) {
              case 'txt':
              echo "<a href='".$dir.$file."'>".$file."</a>"  ?> <button onclick="moveFile('<?php echo $file?>')">Mover arquivo</button>
              <?php
              break;
            }
          }

        }
      }

      ?>
```

O PHP que contém a função para transferir os arquivos:

```
<?php

function moverArquivos($file){

var_dump($file);
$dir = 'files/'.$file;
$destino = 'files/backup/';
copy($dir, $destino);
unlink('files/'.$file);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que sei da função copy do php, a sua função tem o erro de só ter definido a pasta de destino quando é necessário definir todo o nome do arquivo tente ela assim:

```
function moverArquivos($file){
    $fonte = 'files/'.$file;
    $copia = 'files/backup/'.$file;
    $res = copy($fonte , $copia);
    if($res) echo "Arquivo copiado!";
    $res = unlink($fonte);
    if($res) echo "Arquivo original apagado";
}
```

Apesar que pelo que vi na função você esta querendo mover o arquivo não copiar já que você esta apagando o original, o php não tem uma função move() mas tem a função rename() que faz a mesma coisa, então acho que sua função ficaria melhor assim:

```
function moverArquivos($file){
    $fonte = 'files/'.$file;
    $copia = 'files/backup/'.$file;
    $res = rename($fonte , $copia); //A função rename retorna true se teve sucesso ou false se houve falha.
    if($res):
        echo "Arquivo copiado!";
    else:
        echo "Falha ao copiar o arquivo: ".$file;
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O ajax sozinho não consegue chamar sua função, também é necessário passar o arquivo para sua função declarando o atributo data no escorpo da sua função $.ajax.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="50000">
        <title></title>
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function moveFile(fileName) {
                  $.ajax({
                    url:'copyFile.php',
                    type: "GET",
                    data:{
                      "file":fileName
                    },
                    complete: function (fileName) {
                     alert("Arquivo foi movido!");
                   },
                   error: function () {
                    alert('Erro');
                  }
                });  
                  return false;
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['path']))
            $dir =  $_GET['path'];
        else
            $dir = 'fileInfo/';
        foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $file) {
            if (!$file->isDot()) {
                if ($file->isDir()) {
                    echo '<div>';
                    echo '<a href="index.php?path='.$dir. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$file.'"></a><br/>' . $file->getBaseName();
                    echo '</div>';
                } else {
                    switch($file->getExtension()) {
                      case 'txt':
                      echo "<a href='".$dir.$file."'>".$file."</a>"  ?> <button onclick="moveFile('<?php echo $file?>')">Mover arquivo [<?php echo $file?>]</button>
                      <?php
                      break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

E no seu arquivo copyFile.php você recebe o $_GET com o valor passado pela função em js e chama a função em php.

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['file'])){
        moverArquivos($_GET['file']);
    }

    function moverArquivos($file){

    var_dump($file);
    $dir = 'files/'.$file;
    $destino = 'files/backup/';
    copy($dir, $destino);
    unlink('files/'.$file);
    echo "Arquivo Movido!";
    }
    ?>
```